# Redis container stops for a long time

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, nosql, containers

I have a pet project with Redis. When I stop or restart docker compose project, it takes over 10 seconds to stop Redis Docker container (other containers stops within 1 or 2 seconds). Meanwhile Redis container **starts** almost immediately, it takes a lot of times compare to other containers to **stop**. Setting `save` to empty string does not effect.

With `save 60 1` or `save`  it does not take effect to time to stop.

Takes about **10 times more** compare to node.js and Postgres containers on dev machines (Mac M1 Pro and Linux Ryzen 3600 PC) and "pet-production" Intel Xeon virtual server with 2 cores.

Is it way to boost stopping container or restart time for developing at least? I often use `docker compose up -d --build` and it takes some addition time to restart Redis.

I Does't care about Redis data. It can be deleted after restart on development envoronment.

*redis.conf:*

```
loglevel notice

# Modules
loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redisearch.so
loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so
loadmodule /usr/lib/redis/modules/redistimeseries.so

port 0
tls-port 6379

tls-cert-file /certs/server.crt
tls-key-file /certs/server.key
tls-ca-cert-file /certs/ca.crt
tls-dh-params-file /certs/redis.dh

maxmemory 256mb

save # was: `save: 60 1` with the same time to stop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with bash script that does not process SIGTERM signal.

*Dockerfile*:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start-redis.sh"]
```

Old *start-redis.sh*:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

New *start-redis.sh*:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# [ Some work... ]

# Define cleanup function
stop_redis() {
    echo "==========   Stopping Redis server...   =========="
    redis-cli shutdown
    exit 0
}

# Trap SIGINT and SIGTERM signals and run cleanup function
trap stop_redis SIGINT
trap stop_redis SIGTERM

# Start redis
redis-server /usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf &
wait %?redis-server
```